# Pure-FTPD error: Unable to start a standalone server: Address already in use

Tags: ftp, pureftpd

I just installed Pure-FTPD to give it a test run, I added a group and a user

> groupadd test1
>
> useradd -g test1 -d /var/www/html -s /etc testuser

then tried to run the server using

> /usr/sbin/pure-ftpd -S `<ip>`,21 -c 30 -C 1 -l puredb:/etc/pureftpd.pdb -x -E -j -R

and receive this error

> Unable to start a standalone server: Address already in use

I took a look at what was running that may already be using port 21

> grep ftp /etc/services

and see this

> 21 is registered to ftp, but also used by fsp
>
> ftp             21/tcp
>
> ftp             21/udp          fsp fspd

then i took a closer look at port 21

> lsof -i :21

and got this

> COMMAND    PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
>
> pure-ftpd 3709 root    4u  IPv4  12920      0t0  TCP *:ftp (LISTEN)
>
> pure-ftpd 3709 root    5u  IPv6  12922      0t0  TCP *:ftp (LISTEN)

any clues?

Comment: btw /etc/services has nothing to do what is actually listening on a port

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it's already running, kill the pid and try again...

Comment: ok, give me 1 moment

Comment: Or use sudo pure-ftpd restart

Answer (score -1):

I too have same issue like this.

```
Failed to start Pure-FTPd FTP server.
PID file /var/run/pure-ftpd.pid not readable (yet?) after start.
```

I do the following steps:

```
# ps -A | grep ftp
 3080 ?        00:00:00 vsftpd
# kill 3080
```

Again I restarted my pure-ftpd.service and its  active (running).
Its works for me